How do i get vuetify to work with Laravel breeze (Laravel/Vue3/Inertia.js)
It is my first time doing a project using Laravel breeze (Laravel10/Vue3/inertia.js). I have done the back-end and front-end set-up and everything looks good till then. However, I installed Vuetify3.5 and been trying to set it up to work with vue, but vuetify components won't just load. Here is my vuetify.js file;
import "vuetify/styles"
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify"
import * as components from "vuetify/components"
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives"

const customeTheme = {
    colors: {
        primary: "#673ab7",
        secondary: "#424242",
    }
}

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: "customeTheme",
        themes: {
            customeTheme
        }
    }
})

export default vuetify;

and then i imported this file into my app.js file;
import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';
//imported vuetify here
import vuetify from "./vuetify"

const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

//instantiated vuetify in my vue/inertia app
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props), vuetify })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .use(vuetify)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});

From my experience using Laravel/Vue2 with Vuetify, we add <v-app> as a wrapper in our root App.vue file but Laravel breeze/inertia does not structure that way. Do i have to create some root file and add the <v-app> wrapper or what am i doing wrong?
